# How do I change the `prefers-reduced-motion` setting in browsers?

Tags: browser, media-queries, accessibility, settings

There is plenty of documentation around on how to use the [prefers-reduced-motion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion) media query in CSS.

This is great but now that I'm using `prefers-reduced-motion` in my CSS, I want to be able to test what using my site is like for someone that has this setting enabled. I can't find any information on how to do this though and I'm having difficulty finding this as a setting in browser settings.

Maybe this isn't a browser setting at all. Maybe this is something that is set at the Operating System level.

Comment: it literally tells you within the article you referenced :-)

Comment: 'User Preferences' section right near the top of the article tells you for every OS, for some reason somebody thought it necessary to reference the exact same article in their answer and copy paste the same info :-P

Comment: I'm an idiot for not seeing that ‍♂️

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Comment: Hehe, easy to do bud, the annoying thing is that when you toggle it on and off you sometimes have to restart the browser to update changes (also on my Windows 10 machine sometimes you have to change the font size and click apply to update, some strange bug if you toggle it often).

Comment: Does anybody have a way to set this from JavaScript? I want to be able to run my Cypress automated tests in CI while having this setting enabled, and there isn't an easy way to configure the CI environment to set it globally…

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this from JS. It is best to rely on a class still I think since you can give the user the ability to toggle dark mode on and off. It will work well with unit testing as well then. The media query is good for determining what the default theme should be though.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Oh, I didn't see the "[User Preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion#User_Preferences)" section in the mdn documentation. ‍♂️

> For Firefox, the reduce request is honoured if:
>
> - **In GTK/Gnome**, if gtk-enable-animations is set to false. This is configurable via GNOME Tweaks (Appearance tab or General tab, depending on version).
>
>   - Alternately, add `gtk-enable-animations = false` to the [Settings] block of the GTK 3 configuration file (`~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`).
> - **In Windows 10:** Settings > Ease of Access > Display > Show animations in Windows.
> - **In Window 7 [& 8]:** Control Panel > Ease of Access > Make the computer easier to see > Turn off all unnecessary animations (when possible).
> - **In macOS:** System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Reduce motion.
> - **In iOS:** Settings > General > Accessibility > Reduce Motion.
> - **In Android 9+:** Settings > Accessibility > Remove animations.
>
> **Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion#User_Preferences

It says "for Firefox" however since this is a system setting at the OS level, this is likely how you change the setting for all browsers that support this media query.

Comment: Wow! This is absolute insanity that the OS dictates the setting in the browser. They are two very different intents. I deliberately unchecked 'Show Animations in Windows' (a very long time ago) because I don't need Windows to animate everything and even though I thought I had a good graphics card - apparently I don't. I had no idea the system setting affected my browser until I visited https://animate.style/ That's a good test page to verify

Comment: @Simon_Weaver it makes sense for it to use the os setting as the default for the browser. I'm surprised that browsers don't make it simple to switch though. In Firefox I think changing the browser theme let's you overide the dark-theme setting. I'm not sure if this affects websites or not though.

Comment: I agree it makes sense to use the OS setting as the *default* initial value. However that's meaningless if there's no way in the browser to change it independently. The reason I turn Windows animation off is for productivity and annoyance factor. It's a completely different thing to browser animations. Windows should have two checkboxes - one for system and the other for browser. My astonishment comes mostly from the fact I had NO CLUE it was doing this. In iOS it's a different 'feeling' because Safari is so tied to the OS but again I want them to be distinct.

Comment: In Firefox, you can open `about:config` and add `ui.prefersReducedMotion` as a Number and set it to `0` (no) or `1` (yes) to override the OS setting. Delete it and Firefox will honor the OS setting again. Changes take effect immediately.

Answer (score 13):

This should be an OS setting, I know in Mac OS it is under: System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Reduce motion.

In Windows 10: Settings > Ease of Access > Display > Show animations in Windows.

More info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion

Also please note not all browsers support or honor the setting

Comment: In Windows 11: Settings > Accessibility > Visual Effects > Animation effects

Answer (score 9):

As per the other answers, this is an OS setting.

However, for testing, Chromium-based browsers allow you to temporarily change the setting from the developer tools:

> To simulate the operating system's reduced motion setting, without
> having to change your operating system setting:
>
> 1. Press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` on Windows/Linux or `Command`+`Shift`+`P` on macOS to open the **Command Menu**.
> 2. Type **reduced**, to turn the simulation on and off. Select the **Emulate CSS prefers-reduced-motion** option, and then press `Enter`.
> 3. Refresh the webpage and check whether your animations run.

Source: [Microsoft Edge docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/accessibility/reduced-motion-simulation) on "Simulate reduced motion" (but not specific to Edge).

Comment: When I do this in Chrome, I see the command and there's a red button to the right of it labeled "Rendering..." Clicking on this line or the button, or pressing enter on the keyboard just closes this Command Menu. I can't tell if I've made a change. If I bring it up again I see the same red button.

Comment: Yes, the Command Menu just closes right away. Opening the command menu and searching again, the text has changed from "Emulate CSS prefers-reduced-motion" to "Do not emulate CSS prefers-reduced-motion", so that's one way to check. Also [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/justmaxl/2cwqry3p) should show a check mark next to the currently active setting:

Comment: Thank you so much! I missed that change.

Comment: Annoyingly this only works one way, not the other way around. If OS setting is off, you can use this to emulate it being on. But if the OS setting is on, you CANNOT use this to emulate it being off. The motion is reduced regardless of whether this is "Emulate" or "Do not emulate". I want reduced motion in OS globally (because animations are annoying), but not reduced in the browser because I'm testing a website on the browser. This shouldn't be difficult! (As of the moment, only Firefox has a way to override OS setting being on, but Chrome doesn't.)