# BootStrap 5.0 beta 1 Carousel Slide not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm having trouble making the carousel actually slide. It would just swap to next item without any "slide" transition. I've even went through the BS 5 doc and it doesn't do the slide transition either. Has it been removed?

HTML:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-slide ="true" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="1000" data-bs-pause="hover"> 
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active " style = "background-color:red">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style = "background-color:blue">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style = "background-color:yellow">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-item {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 > Display > Tick show animations in windows

Comment: That setting is on by default. See also https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/accessibility/#reduced-motion.

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708960/how-do-i-change-the-preferes-reduced-motion-setting-in-browsers.