# Progress bar (b-progress-bar) not animating

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I added a simple `b-progress-bar` to my code in order to show some percentages. I followed the official documentation step by step, and everything is showing nicely, except for the animation part. Here is the component html:

```
      <b-progress max="100" :animated="true" :striped="true" show-progress>
        <b-progress-bar :value="balance"  variant="danger"
                        :label-html="(balance/100) * 100 + '%'" />
      </b-progress>
```

When the component displays, it doesn't move, stripes are there alongside everything else, but the animation is missing. Another thing I noted is that even the progress bar in the documentation isn't being animated for me. Could it be a browser problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've probably enabled `prefers-reduced-motion` in your OS or Browser, which disables most animations in Bootstrap.

Comment: @Hiws I just checked, `prefers-reduced-motion` is disabled in my browser.

Comment: And what about your OS? I believe most OS have an option which reduces animations as well, and your browser likely respects that if its enabled. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59708982/8397974

Comment: You're right, it was OS-related. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon such a dumb issue, please check your Windows/Browser settings to see whether you have disabled animations.

I personally disabled animation on my whole PC to speed it up, and that was blocking the  from doing anything visual.