Animations not working on my whole system
I'm contacting you because I'm literally going crazy with my computer and javascript.
I'm a web designer and I'm having a major problem with javascript animations on numerous sites, for no apparent reason.
My computer is an HP Omen 16' and here's my current configuration:

Windows 11
AMD Ryzen 9
Nvidia Geforce RTX 3070 Ti

To put it simply, some animations don't work or are simply not interpreted on all my browsers (in private browsing or not, even on browsers reinstalled from 0).
To give you some concrete examples, here's what I'm seeing from my side:
Site 1: https://just-dev.fr/ (made with Framer)
 https://www.loom.com/share/6b404e4f18dc49e38dbb30ca997655b7
Absolutely no animations are working.
--
Site 2: https://designvolt.co/fr/ (another made with Framer)
 https://www.loom.com/share/678bcf99c7d942dc9a553ae76eb881cc
Here only marquee animations are not working.
--
Site 3 : https://www.apple.com/fr/airpods-4/
 https://www.loom.com/share/263f2b38dec94093b92141a4a68f5e80
No animations are working, in the end you see console with errors if that can help :
BubbleGum::addComponent unsupported component 'StaggeredFadeIn'. Reason: 'StaggeredFadeIn.IS_SUPPORTED' returned false  main.built.js:1
BubbleGum::addComponent unsupported component 'ArLink'. Reason: 'ArLink.IS_SUPPORTED' returned false main.built.js:1 
BubbleGum::addComponent unsupported component 'PurpleGradient'. Reason: 'PurpleGradient.IS_SUPPORTED' returned false main.built.js:1 
BubbleGum::addComponent unsupported component 'Redesigned'. Reason: 'Redesigned.IS_SUPPORTED' returned false main.built.js:1 
BubbleGum::addComponent unsupported component 'VideoScroll'. Reason: 'VideoScroll.IS_SUPPORTED' returned false
It clearly says that their animations are not supported on my browser (same error on other browsers).
--
It's impossible to know where these Javascript problems are coming from, it's driving me crazy.
It seems to be affecting the whole system.
I've already tried the following:

Install Node.js (you never know)
Uninstall / reinstall Java
Reinstall original Windows files
Disable antivirus protection
Use computer in safe mode

Honestly, I don't know what else to do....
Fortunately, this only affects certain sites (especially Framer sites, which have to use a special JS techo). My WordPress / Elementor sites work very well, as do some immersive sites with very complex animations, it's really beyond comprehension.
If anyone has a clue how to help me, it would be incredible.

Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask] - Is this an actual programming related issue?

Have you maybe enabled a "reduced motion" mode? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708960/how-do-i-change-the-prefers-reduced-motion-setting-in-browsers

Not directly programming issue, however it seems that it is something related to JS setting on the machine and how it's interpreted. Can be related, what you think?

@AKX OH MY GOD !!! YOU ARE MY SAVIOR  !!! THANKS !!

Glad to help :)
